# Which prerequisites are there for crystal reports 2008 and .mdf file

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I have created a small application in Visual Studio 2008 using Crystal Reports and Microsoft SQL Server as database (.mdf file). I have created the setup of that application which runs in my system perfectly but doesn't work in other system. Exception is raised on CrystalDecisions namespace. How many and which prerequisites are required to be added in that setup project for Crystal reports and .mdf file.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Copy Local = True  in Crystal references
[image]

Comment: Thank you your answer. Where can I find this?

Comment: I am not able to find CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design namespace. Instead I have CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine namespace in .vb file. I tried to import CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design but it was not found.

Comment: you  should  install crystal report to find references if you already installed it you can add references by (  right click on reference - > add reference and browse for It !